# Border radius not working for img tag with width property

Tags: html, css, image, object-fit

I need to make round corners for image in div. Image shoul contain this div.
Here is my realisation of that:

```css
.img-module {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70vh;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div className='img-module'>
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Every thing is fine without width property, but without width wide images will not fit to the div and go outside it. With stated width wide images fit the div normally but border-radius become disabled somewhy and images's corners become stamdart.
Could comebody tell me how can i fix it?

High pic with width on:
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwaj6.png)

High pic with width off:
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqYTi.png)

Wide pic with width on:
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoGet.png)

Wide pic with width off:
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH7yg.png)

I tried to google it but unsuccessfully...

Comment: use cover instead of contain

Comment: could you provide a reproduction?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks for your answer, but cover do not satisfied style of the page. Moreover, picture will be cutted, when i need to display all image area.

Comment: @Sheraff, i have added to my initial question links with reproduction. please see above.

Comment: @AlexCap I meant could you provide some code that reproduces the issue. The code you initially provided could not be executed, and so required extra effort to debug. I've converted it to a snippet without changing anything else, and it seems to have a visible border radius.

Comment: Most of the time, providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) actually makes the issue almost trivial to solve, and if it doesn't it helps other people identify it.

Comment: Please edit your snippet so that it demonstrates the problem. Perhaps include different images and different styles so that we can see which ones work and which don't work.

Comment: well noted, i'll correct my question asap